# Use certificate to make API requests in Java

Tags: java, ssl

Below I have included code that takes a Thumbprint of a certificate as an argument and then loads the appropriate cert from the Windows certificate store.

This was done because now I would like to use the found cert to make API calls to an API that requires this certificate- if the certificate is not included in the request the API will reject me as unauthorized. 
I have previously done this in C# and it was quite simple as I was able to just create a clientHandler that identified the protocol, callback, and certificate that allowed for creation of a usable HttpClient. Java is significantly more complicated and is giving me issues since it appears I must work with the `keymanager`(and possibly `trustStore` and `SSLContext`). In other words I am having a hard time understanding how to use these objects to send my certificate to the API with my request.

I realize I may not be able to simply build the client with the cert to get the successful connection. But how can I use the x509certificate that I have in memory to successfully send requests to the API.

I am not looking for a solution that will 100% work for my case, I would just like to see a clean example of how to send an API request with the certificate(in whichever way the libraries require) in Java.

```
 public static X509Certificate LoadCert(String inThumbprint) {

    X509Certificate ReturnCert = null;

    try{
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        keyStore.load(null, null);  // Load keystore

        String currentAlias;
        X509Certificate foundCert;
        String calculatedThumbprint;

        for (Enumeration<String> oEnum = keyStore.aliases(); oEnum.hasMoreElements();) {

            currentAlias = oEnum.nextElement();                                                     System.out.println(currentAlias);
            foundCert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(currentAlias);
            calculatedThumbprint = getThumbprint(foundCert);                                        System.out.println(calculatedThumbprint);

            if (calculatedThumbprint.equals(inThumbprint)) {
                ReturnCert = foundCert;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ReturnCert;
}

private static String getThumbprint(X509Certificate cert)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateEncodingException {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] der = cert.getEncoded();
    md.update(der);
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    String digestHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digest);
    return digestHex.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: *...to an API that requires this certificate...*  Requires it how? *...and is giving me issues...* That's not really a useful description of a problem. Can you be more specific?

Comment: ...Issues: I am having a hard time understanding how to use the java ssl and security libs to include the certificate in my API request. ... In C#  I was able to simply include the certificate, but it appears I cannot do that in Java.